# Adding a line of words towards the bottom of chart

Tags: highcharts

I would like to add a line of words "Country: Singapore Reporting Date: d/MMM/yy User: xxxxx " towards the bottom of chart. How should I proceed? Currently, I have my codes as below.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  function renderChart(divId, chartType, chartTitle, chartData, categories) {

     var data = jQuery.parseJSON(chartData);
     var cat = jQuery.parseJSON(categories);
     console.log(cat);
     console.log(chartData);
     var options = createOption(divId, chartType, chartTitle, cat);
     options.series = [{
           allowPointSelect : true,
           data : data,
           showInLegend : true            
        }];
     var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
  }

  function createOption(divId, chartType, chartTitle, categories) {
     var options = {
        colors : [ '#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00',
              '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4' ],
        chart : {
           renderTo : divId,
           type : chartType
        },
        title : {
           text : chartTitle
        },
        xAxis : {
           categories : categories,
           showEmpty: false
        },
        yAxis: {
              showEmpty: false
          },
        series : []

     };

     return options;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [labels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#labels) or [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text%28%29), which allow to add custom text / object on the chart.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added this. But I don't see the text. Anything wrong with it? labels: {
           items: [{
            html: 'Chart criteria here.....',
            style: {
             position: 'fixed',
             bottom: '0px',
             left: '0'
            }
           }]
          }

Comment: You need to set top/lef parameter, but I advice to use renderer.

Comment: I would like to place the text at the bottom left corner. Any way we can do this instead of manually assign a number for positioning? I have the codes here      events: {
                  load: function() {
                      var text = this.renderer.text(chartCriteria, 0, 0).css({
                          bottom : '0',
                          left : '0'
                      }).add();
                  }
              }

Comment: Css will not solve problem, you need to declare it in renderer like here http://jsfiddle.net/X2ZAw/ in case when it should be placed no in the plotArea, i adivce to check chart object, and get correct values (like height).